# How can I set exactly 10 tick marks in pyplot?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I've seen a lot of solutions where the tick marks are placed at specific location: I want the tick marks to be automatically spaced, but I only want ten of them. I haven't seen any solutions for setting an exact number of ticks. Preferably, the ends of the figure will also be labeled with the tick marks. How can I just set the number of tick marks?

Answer (score -1):

```
pyplot.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)   # y-axis

pyplot.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=10)  # x-axis

pyplot.locator_params(nbins=10)   # both
```

See also: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.locator_params

Comment: nticks didn't work, but nbins did.